# Jquery Radio button value not changing

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, radio-button

Need some help, ive searched google and have no luck.

I am trying to update my radios-button's value in the div class "size-number". That value I want use it within the ajax request below. When i inspect element, the radio-button has the updated value of the button available but when i console.log it in jquery, it gives me the same initial value, despite which i pick. Ive tried setting the radio-buttons to checked="checked". Also i believe its a matter of the default value. Ive also tried input validation within jquery. In addition, ive attempted to reference the input ("input[name='radiobten']:checked") in jquery as well. any suggestions would very appreciated!

```js
$(".size-number").click(function(){
  
  var modelid = $("#modelval").attr('value');
  console.log(modelid);
 
  $.ajax({
    url: '"Example API"',
    data:  [],
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    success: function(res){
      var newarr = (res).filter(function(indx){
        return indx.model_cat_id == modelid
      });
      console.log(newarr)
      $('modelselect').slideToggle(200).html(res);
    }});
});
```

```html
<?php foreach ($brands as $brand){ ?>
    <div class="search-select">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <a href="/<?php echo $brand->full_slug.$urlSize; ?>">
        
        <?php echo $brand->name; ?></a>
        
    </div>
    <?php
        $slugCurrent = $brand->slug;
        foreach ($models as $model){
            if($model->brand_id == $brand->id){
            if(is_null($model->model_cat_id)){?>
                <div class="size-number" style="display: none;">
                    <a href="/<?php echo $brand->slug; ?>/<?php echo $model->slug_full.$urlSize; ?>" style="color: blue;"><?php echo $model->name; ?><input type="radio" id="modelval" name="radiobten" value="<?php echo $model->id?>"/></a>
                </div>

                <?php    
            }
                
            }
        }
    }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple element with same id i.e : `modelval`. This will always give you value of first radio button no matter which button you choose.Instead use `class` to get value of radio button.So ,onclick of div you can use `$(this).find("yourclassname").attr('value')` to get value of that particular button only.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(".size-number").click(function() {
  //div->find closest modelval->value
  var modelid = $(this).find(".modelval").attr('value');
  console.log(modelid);

  $.ajax({
    url: '"Example API"',
    data: [],
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    success: function(res) {
      var newarr = (res).filter(function(indx) {
        return indx.model_cat_id == modelid
      });
      console.log(newarr)
      $('modelselect').slideToggle(200).html(res);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="size-number" >
  <a href="/<?php echo $brand->slug; ?>/<?php echo $model->slug_full.$urlSize; ?>" style="color: blue;">Abc<input type="radio" class="modelval" name="radiobten" value="1"/></a>
</div>
<div class="size-number" >
  <a href="/<?php echo $brand->slug; ?>/<?php echo $model->slug_full.$urlSize; ?>" style="color: blue;">Xyz<input type="radio" class="modelval" name="radiobten" value="2"/></a>
</div>
```